# Is there a way to open a ~120 GB file with polars

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

I have a big file ~120 Gb with ~20 columns and millions of rows, the problem is that I'm using Polars for speed but still when I use collect on the dataframe even if it is for show me a single column it takes too long, I dont know how much because while I wait for the column the kernel of the jupyter notebook dies

```
PATH = test.csv
df = pl.scan_csv(PATH)
print(df.select('First Column').collect())
```

I expect the First Column in a reasonable time.

Comment: ```collect()``` will load the entire data set into memory, which can be really slow, especially for large data sets. try to ```pl.read_csv``` instead (to load as a DataFrame) and select only the first column

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH = "test.csv"
df = pl.read_csv(PATH)
first_column = df['First Column']
print(first_column)
# or
print(first_column.head())
```

Comment: Your answer will read the whole file into memory on the second line - one needs to use scan_csv, then select the column, and *then* collect.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your dataset is just too big to print an entire column. But why are you wanting to print an entire column, when its likely much longer than you could fit on your screen? Start with just printing the first few rows (df.head()):

```py
PATH = "test.csv" # filename, as a string
df = pl.scan_csv(PATH) # read the file lazily
# assuming "First Column" is the name of the first column:
df_head = df.select("First Column").head().collect()
print(df_head)
```

Comment: It was an example, because I did this also and still takes too long to print out

Answer (score 0):

A 120 GB csv file sounds really bad…

Your jupyter kernel will probably die anyway, and such a monster will not fit in memory, it is too big even if you open it in a normal .py file.

I suggest to try with a normal python file and start to filter your data in the lazyframe, before actually collecting it.

If you do not know which values you are looking for, try to merge and count or to have a description of the file.

option 2: work on a powerful server
option 3: create a DB table or smt similar, maybe set up a postgres DB and use pgloader to load the csv in pg

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you only want to obtain a few rows for that column. For that, you can use `fetch()`.

Here is an example:

```
PATH = test.csv
df = pl.scan_csv(PATH)
df.select('First Column').fetch(10)
```

This example will show 10 rows from the column.

Here is the link for the Polars API reference on fetch: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.fetch.html#polars.LazyFrame.fetch